# PySide Custom Widget w/ Pixmap error (QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2)

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have written my first custom widget -- a small status light I use to show the progress of a background task.  I am doing something wrong as I repeatedly keep getting the following error emitted when the mouse is over, or interacting with the Qt Window that contains the custom widget:

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
```

The application does not crash but keeps dumping this error to std out. I am fairly new to Qt and have looked around a bit to try and figure out how to resolve this issue to no avail. I am hoping someone with more Qt experience than I can walk me through the proper way to go about implementing a custom widget with a paintEvent().  I have attached the code below:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class LightWidget(QtGui.QLabel):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(LightWidget,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())
        self.setMinimumSize(15,15)
        self.setMaximumSize(15,15)
        self.set_fill_color(.6,.6,.6)
        self.set_line_color(0,0,0)
        self.set_line_width(1)

    def set_fill_color(self,r,b,g,a=1.0,hsv=False):
        ncolor=QtGui.QColor()
        if hsv:
            ncolor.setHsvF(r,g,b,a)
        else:
            ncolor.setRgbF(r,g,b,a)
        self._fill_color=ncolor

    def set_line_color(self,r,g,b,a=1.0,hsv=False):
        ncolor=QtGui.QColor()
        if hsv:
            ncolor.setHsvF(r,g,b,a)
        else:
            ncolor.setRgbF(r,g,b,a)
        self._line_color=(ncolor)

    def set_line_width(self,width):
        self._line_width=width

    def paintEvent(self,e):
        painter=QtGui.QPainter(self.pixmap())
        painter.begin(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        radx=self.width()*0.5
        rady=self.height()*0.5
        offset=self._line_width
        center=QtCore.QPoint(radx,rady)

        gradient = QtGui.QRadialGradient(center
                                         ,radx
                                         ,QtCore.QPointF(radx*0.5, rady*0.5))
        c_color = QtGui.QColor(0,0,0,0)
        c_color.setHsvF(self._fill_color.hueF()
                        ,self._fill_color.saturationF()
                        ,max(min(self._fill_color.valueF()*1.5,1.0),0) )
        o_color = QtGui.QColor(0,0,0,0)
        o_color.setHsvF(self._fill_color.hueF()
                        ,self._fill_color.saturationF()
                        ,max(min(self._fill_color.valueF()*.5,1),0))

        gradient.setColorAt(0, c_color)
        gradient.setColorAt(0.25, self._fill_color)
        gradient.setColorAt(1, o_color)

        pen=QtGui.QPen()
        pen.setColor(self._line_color)
        pen.setWidthF(self._line_width)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(gradient)

        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(gradient)
        painter.drawEllipse(center,radx-offset,rady-offset)
        painter.end()


def test():
    form = QtGui.QWidget()
    wid = LightWidget(form)
    form.setWindowTitle('Status Light Widget')
    form.show()
    return form

def main():
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window =test()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're conflating what you paint on:

```py
def paintEvent(self,e):
    # Here you start the painter on the pixmap
    painter=QtGui.QPainter(self.pixmap())
    # But here you start it on the widget proper
    painter.begin(self) 
    ...
```

The truth is, you don't need any pixmaps, and you don't need to derive from `QLabel`. Derive from `QWidget`, and paint directly on the widget:

```
def paintEvent(self,e):
    painter=QtGui.QPainter(self)
    # The begin() is redundant. Don't invoke it.
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.. or status light I should say :)